# Equilibrium index of a given sequence: What is the best algorithm to find one?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, math

Equilibrium index of a sequence is an index such that the sum of elements at lower indexes is equal to the sum of elements at higher indexes. For example, in a sequence A:

```
A[0]=-7 A[1]=1 A[2]=5 A[3]=2 A[4]=-4 A[5]=3 A[6]=0
```

3 is an equilibrium index, because:

```
A[0]+A[1]+A[2]=A[4]+A[5]+A[6]
```

6 is also an equilibrium index, because:

```
A[0]+A[1]+A[2]+A[3]+A[4]+A[5]=0
```

(sum of zero elements is zero) 7 is not an equilibrium index, because it is not a valid index of sequence A.
If you still have doubts, this is a precise definition: the integer k is an equilibrium index of a sequence   if and only if  and  .

Assume the sum of zero elements is equal zero. Write a function

```
int equi(int[] A);
```

that given a sequence, returns its equilibrium index (any) or -1 if no equilibrium indexes exist. Assume that the sequence may be very long.

Comment: For those trying to read this, the sequence is `{-7, 1, 5, 2 -4, 3, 0}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Calculate the total sum of all of the elements in `A`
2. For every index `i`, calculate the sum of the elements from `A[0]` to  `A[i - 1]`, until the sum is equal to `(totalSum - A[i]) / 2`.

Note that the sum of elements from `A[0]` to `A[i - 1]` can be tracked as a running total, which means that the complexity of the whole algorithm is O(n). Implementing as code is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This might fail on an arbitrary series, because the equilibrium index doesn't always involve all elements of the series. In the series {1,2,3,4,5,10}, 4 would be an equilibrium index per the definition given, but the sum of elements 0 - 3 is 10, which is less than the sum of the elements divided by 2. In fact, there is no subset of elements that sum to that value, yet there is an equilibrium index.

Comment: True, so to amend the answer `if we find our partial sum to be greater than half of the whole sum, return -1;`

Comment: @Harper, I didn't see that the definition of "equilibrium index" excludes the value at that index. I've updated my answer.

Comment: looks like that gets it then. Makes sense, and passes the tests I can see. Keeping it O(n) just makes it better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses `O(n)` memory. Compute `S[i] = A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[i]`. Then the sum of a subsequence `[i, j]` is `Sum(i, j) = S[j] - S[i - 1]` (`S[x < 0] = 0`).

So for each `i` from `0` to `A.Length - 1` check if `Sum(0, i - 1) = Sum(i + 1, A.Length - 1)`.

In fact, if you're allowed to destroy the given array, you don't even need `S`, you can do it all in `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudocode - worst case is 2 passes through A.

```
R = sum(A)
L = e = 0
for i = 0 .. A.size
  L+=e
  R-=(e=A[i])
  return i if L==R
end
return NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

> a = (-7, 1, 5, 2, -4, 3, 0)
>
> sumleft = 0
>
> sumright = 0
>
> for i in range(len(a)):
>
> ```
> for j in range(i+1,len(a)):
>
>     sumright += a[j]
>
> if sumright == sumleft:
>
>     print i
>
> sumleft += a[i]
>
> sumright = 0
> ```